# Why does BeautifulSoup not find the tags containing text but I can run a "find" and see the text in the HTML?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python 3.7 and BeautifulSoup 4.  What's the right way to search for tags that contain specific text?  I thought I could do this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(code, features="lxml")
...
no_images_msgs = ["No very similar images were found.", "No similar images were found."]
for no_images_msg in no_images_msgs:
    elts = soup.body.findAll(text=re.compile("^.*" + no_images_msg + ".*$"))
    print("index:" + str(code.find(no_images_msg)))
    print("searched for " + no_images_msg + " found:" + str(len(elts)))
```

but interestingly, even though the "find" call returns a positive number indicating the specified string can be found in the HTML code, the "findAll" call fails to find anything.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are certain the string is contained in the <body>? With the call to find you are searching the entire page. Might be something else though.

Comment: Can you provide an url and expected result count?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it `find_all()`? I just checked the documentation and they renamed findAll in BeautifulSoup 4.